# Convert base64 to multipart form-data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, base64, multipartform-data

I'm using ng-img-crop for cropping an image before uploading to server. The crop image is a base64 string, but the server accept only multipart form data. So what are my options to convert it? Thanks in advance..

Comment: [Convert Data URI to File then append to FormData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata) The answer in above question works.

Comment: Thanks for the link... :)